# AR ODG application for conference calls

Tags: augmented-reality, vuforia, wikitude, artoolkit, kudan

I'm researching AR frameworks in order to select the best option for developing conference call/ meeting application for ODG glasses.

I got only a few directions for selecting a framework:

Performance of video streaming (capturing and encoding) must be watched closely  to avoid overheating and excessive power consumption,

Should support extended tracking and

Video capturing should not be frame by frame.

I have no experience with AR field in general, and I would really appreciate if you can let me know your opinion or to give me some guidance on how to choose the best-fitted framework.

Comment: You should edit your question. It isn't clear what you are trying to do, so it's hard to help you.

Comment: According to our [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) guidance, "**Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:**...Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic..."

Answer (score 1):

[For ODG](http://www.osterhoutgroup.com/products-r7-glasses), you should use Vuforia according software details :

> Qualcomm Technologies Inc.'s VuforiaTM SDK for Digital Eyewear

Vuforia supports extended tracking. According to what you are asking, you'll need more than just an AR SDK. You'll need to identify what you want exactly. Do you want an application that let the user see with who he's talking or do you want some holographic stuff? Depending on what you want, maybe smartglasses isn't what you need and at this point you should try to learn more about the differents SDK out there. I suggest you to look at [this](http://cases.azoft.com/top-5-tools-creating-augmented-reality-apps/) and [that](http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/augmented-reality-sdks).